# Meteor Session and browser refreshes

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

Do Meteor sessions get reset when there is a page refresh?

For some reason I did not think they did but it seems like they do. Is there a way to make them persist?

If not what would be the best solution for this?

I want to allow the same data to show if a user refreshes (this data is specific to the user) even if they are not registered yet.

Comment: I save some common data in Meteor.user, When page refresh u can set it back.

Comment: Yeah, it's just I'd like persistance even when they are not logged in.

Answer (score 10):

Actually what you could do is create a "subclass" of Session that stores the value in Amplify's store when set() is called. You would automatically inherit all the reactive properties of Session. Here is the code, it worked for me:

```
SessionAmplify = _.extend({}, Session, {
  keys: _.object(_.map(amplify.store(), function(value, key) {
    return [key, JSON.stringify(value)]
  })),
  set: function (key, value) {
    Session.set.apply(this, arguments);
    amplify.store(key, value);
  },
});
```

Just replace all your Session.set/get calls with SessionAmplify.set/get calls. When set() is called, the parent Session method is called, as well as amplify.store(). When the "subclass" is first created, it loads everything that is in amplify's store inside its keys, so that they can be retrieved right away with get().

You can test a working variation of the Leaderboard example here: https://github.com/sebastienbarre/meteor-leaderboard

Comment: how could i use this technique if i only wanted to persist one key in particular of Session with amplifyjs, but otherwise let all the other keys behave as usual ? is there a way to adapt your method ?

Comment: not sure if sebastien.b is the same author, but exactly this code is available as a package, via installing with mrt add session-amplify. github project here: https://github.com/cramrov/meteor-session-amplify

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but it's the second hit on a search for "meteor session manager", so I think it's important to add that the package u2622:persistent-session solves this issue perfectly.

from the docs at:
https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session

> Installation
>
> meteor add u2622:persistent-session
>
> That's it! Now you can use Session.setPersistent to set a session
>   variable that will save after a refresh.
>
> If you'd like, you can have Session.set do this as well. See the
>   Options section below.

Comment: Thanks for this one. It worked for me. Only thing I needed to change in my code was: to change Session.set(.. to Session.setAuth( ; and Session.clearAuth(.. on logout.

Comment: Its might be useful here to note that, under the hood of persistent-session, its amplify only thats working!!

Answer (score 4):

I've just created the [UserSession](https://github.com/BenjaminRH/meteor-user-session) package for Atmosphere, which is basically a user-based persistent `Session`.

Comment: for clarity, this package saves session variables in a server side collection. if you're looking for client side storage of session variables, this is nicely achieved with amplify, as per sebastien.b's answer.

Comment: Good package, but it relays on userId, meaning that we need a logged in user. :(

Answer (score 1):

So I think the best way to do this is to use the amplifyJS package.

Here is someones gist that shows how they used it:
https://gist.github.com/2865146

Answer (score 0):

The `Session` is a global key value store, a reactive one.

http://docs.meteor.com/#session

> Session provides a global object on the client that you can use to store an arbitrary set of key-value pairs. Use it to store things like the currently selected item in a list.
>
> What's special about Session is that it's reactive. If you call Session.get("currentList") from inside a template, the template will automatically be rerendered whenever Session.set("currentList", x) is called.

If you have to persist something in the client, you could use the browsers `localstorage` or cookies if you care for older browsers.

Comment: That's actually what the Amplify package does, except with all kinds of fallback support.