# Meteor js : make Session object partially persistent

Tags: session, meteor

In my meteor app I'm using Session to store temporary info about user activity. I'd like to persist some parts of this info to the browser with amplify.js, but not all of it.

I'd like a way to have 'temporary' Session keys and 'persistent' Session keys. Eg I could call

```
Session.set('persistent', 'this is persisted to browser memory');
Session.set('temporary', 'this will be erased on page reload, etc');
```

and then after a page reload

```
Session.get('persistent'); // returns 'this is persisted to browser memory'
Session.get('temporary'); // returns undefined
```

I found [a related post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14659101/1094784) but this saves this approach persists the entire Session object, which I don't want to do. Also, I don't want to use MongoDB for this, I'd like the storage to be purely client side...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: From what I understand, the linked post would work for you. Use the normal `Session` when you want 'temporary' session keys, and use the extended `SessionAmplify` when you want 'persistent' session keys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `localStorage`. It's a little tricky if you want it to be reactive, but I guess you could use `Session` to get that done alongside `localStorage`

When starting up get the item from your browser's localStorage jar

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Session.set("yourItem", localStorage.getItem("yourItem"));
});
```

When setting it:

```
localStorage.setItem("yourItem", "yourValue");
Session.set("yourItem", localStorage.getItem("yourItem"));
```

One thing that's not possible unless you use MongoDB or something is if you set this on one tab, it wont change on the others until you refresh the page. But I guess Session is like this anyway.

Comment: I agree with localstorage, though I'd use amplify (which functions as an interface on top of localstorage, cookies, and related stuff)

Comment: why do we need `Session` then?

Comment: @VictorFerreira To make it reactive. localStorage on its own isn't reactive.

Answer (score 7):

I had success with using the package `u2622:persistent-session` leverages `amplify.js` local storage ability while letting you use the Meteor `Session` object to set and access info.

After doing `meteor add u2622:persistent-session`, you can then go on and do stuff like:

- `Session.setPersistent(key, value)`
- `Session.setDefaultPersistent(key, value)`

`u2622:persistent-session` maintains your data across tabs and reloads, unless you manually clear the browser's localStorage.

Checkout the Github [page](https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session/) for more info