# Session is not defined within Meteor.methods on server side but is on client side

Tags: meteor

I have a method that sets the session variable:

```
Meteor.methods({
    updateSomething: (k) => {
        CollectionOfSomething.insert({
            k: k
        });
        Session.set('latestSomething', CollectionOfSomething.findOne({
            k: k
        });
    }
});
```

What happens next is something contradictory to me. Since the methods are defined within `lib` folder (which is a correct way to do), a call invokes the method both on client and on the server. On the client, it yields new value for the session variable `latestSomething`, and it refreshes every time. But on the server, I'm getting an exception:

```
Exception while invoking method 'updateSomething' ReferenceError: Session is not defined
```

This exception is just a warning and doesn't kill the app instance. But it seems not a good practice, and all those messages stuff the server logs without any value.

What should I do then? What's the Meteor idiomatic way to do?

Answer (score 4):

The `Session` object is only available on the client (see http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/session - both of the function definition boxes say "Client"). Your best option is to `return` the result of your `CollectionOfSomething.findOne()` fetch and then use `Session.set` in the client's callback function.

The `Session` is an ephemeral object that is lost on a hard page refresh or when the user manually navigates to a different page, so maintaining it on the server wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: "The Session is an ephemeral object that is lost when the page reloads or the route changes" the entire purpose of `Session` is **exactly not that**.

Comment: @Kyll, can you link to a source for that statement? The reason that packages like https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session/ exist is because the Session variable only lasts for the life of the current page, hence the name "Session".

Comment: `Session` is a named global `ReactiveDict` which are built to persist across hot reloads and route changes. Your statement is at best very imprecise.

Comment: Again, do you have a source for that? The Meteor I'm familiar with does not work like that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617803/meteor-js-make-session-object-partially-persistent. The purpose of `Session` isn't persistence, it's built-in reactivity.

Comment: @IsaacLyman, `Session` will be lost on hard page reffres, but they will last longer than the current route and over hot-code pushes. Would be strange not to, hence they are based on a pure `ReactiveDict`.

Comment: @RaduChiriac, I probably could have been more clear about what I meant; I was referring to hard refreshes and page reloads from links. Answer edited.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use session on the server. It's meant for reactivity on the client. Set it on the callback like so:

```
Meteor.call('updateSomething', yourThing, function (err, id) {
  if (!err) {
    Session.set('somevar', id);
  }
})
```

where your meteor method looks like this

```
Meteor.methods({
  updateSomething: function (thing) {
    return MyCollection.insert(thing);  // returns the id
  }
});
```